# index going wrong in for loop and if clauses in R

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have a for loop with if statements. For some reason the code is not evaluating when `i = .01` it seems to still evaluate the previous if statement instead. The code produces this:

```
boom for change  0.01  needs  0  quarters,  0  dimes,  0  nickels and  1  pennies 
boom for change  0.02  needs  0  quarters,  0  dimes,  0  nickels and  2  pennies 
boom for change  0.03  needs  0  quarters,  0  dimes,  0  nickels and  3  pennies 
boom for change  0.04  needs  0  quarters,  0  dimes,  0  nickels and  4  pennies 
zoom for change  0.05  needs  0  quarters,  0  dimes,  1  nickels and  0  pennies 
zoom for change  0.06  needs  0  quarters,  0  dimes,  1  nickels and  1  pennies 
zoom for change  0.07  needs  0  quarters,  0  dimes,  1  nickels and  2  pennies 
zoom for change  0.08  needs  0  quarters,  0  dimes,  1  nickels and  3  pennies 
zoom for change  0.09  needs  0  quarters,  0  dimes,  1  nickels and  4  pennies 
zoom for change  0.1  needs  0  quarters,  0  dimes,  1  nickels and  5  pennies
```

**However I want the last line to read**

```
haha for change  0.1  needs  0  quarters,  1  dimes,  0  nickels and  0  pennies
```

Here is my code, you can run it and get all the same results I have.

```
testchange <- seq(.01,.1, by =.01)

q <- .25
d <- .1
n <- .05
p <- .01
qNumber <- 0
dNumber <- 0
nNumber <- 0
pNumber <- 0


for(i in testchange)
{


if(i < .05)
{pNumber <- (i*100)
testy <- "boom"}

else if( i >= .05 & i < .1)
{
testy <- "zoom"
if(i%%n == 0)
{nNumber <- (i/n)
newNum3 <- 0}
else if(i%%n != 0)
{newNum3 <- (100*(i%%n))}

if(newNum3 < 5)
{
  pNumber <- newNum3
}

} 

if( i >= .1 & i < .25)
{
testy <- "haha"
if(i%%d == 0)
{dNumber <- (i/d)
newNum2 <- 0
newNum3 <- 0}
else if(i%%d != 0)
{newNum2 <- (100*(i%%d))}

if(newNum2 >=5 )
{
  if(newNum2%%n == 0)
  {nNumber <- (i/n)
  newNum3 <- 0}
  else if(newNum2%%n != 0)
  { newNum3 <- (100*(i%%n))}

}
if(newNum2 < 5)
{
  pNumber <- newNum2
}
if(newNum3 < 5)
{
  pNumber <- newNum3
}

}
cat(testy, "for change " , i , " needs " , qNumber 
    , " quarters, " , dNumber , " dimes, " , nNumber
    , " nickels and " , pNumber , " pennies","\n" )
}
```

Comment: Produce http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and do something with indentation to make your code more readable.

Comment: just run it and autoindent in your editor.....

Comment: I am not going to do it.  You want us to spend our time and help you for free, so you should make any effort to make it easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is round-off error.  The last step of your loop produced a number very close to but under 0.1.    If you change your line

```
    if( i >= .1 & i < .25)
```

to

```
    if( i + 0.00001 >= .1 & i < .25)
```

You will get the answer that you expect.   Note that you should make many similar changes elsewhere.

Comment: I see, this does answer why the statement was not evaluating but now it shows 2 nickels not 1 dime.... back to drawing board. Thanks!

Comment: could you possibly tell me how it is possible that `i` could change its value and not be .1 exactly?

Comment: Computer arithmetic is base 2.  You cannot exactly represent 0.1 in a finite number of binary digits.   Take a look at the [Wikipedia Article on Round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error)